# "Essential discriminants" of fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, fields

Let $L$ be a number field, and let $K_1, \cdots, K_r$ be the maximal subfields of $L$ (that is, $K_j \subset L$ but for each $j$ there does not exist a proper subfield field $M_j$ of $L$ such that $K_j \subset M_j \subset L$). Let $\Delta(L)$ denote the discriminant of $L$ (respectively, $\Delta(K_j)$ is the discriminant of $K_j$). Define the *essential discriminant* of $L$ to be

$$\displaystyle \Delta^\ast(L) = \frac{\Delta(L)}{\prod_{j=1}^r \Delta(K_j)}.$$

Is $\Delta^\ast(L)$ always an integer? If so, what are the arithmetic/geometric interpretations for it?

Note that when $L$ is a *primitive field*, meaning it doesn't contain any proper subfields other than $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\Delta^\ast(L) = \Delta(L)$. As a trivial consequence, all cubic and quadratic fields have essential discriminants which are integers. One can also check that for any $D_4$ or $C_4$-quartic field the essential discriminant is always an integer.

Comment: I have no idea offhand about your original question, but what if you multiply by the discriminants of the maximal subfields of the K_j, then divide by the maximal subfields of those, etc. and get some sort of multiplicative inclusion-exclusion-type expression?

Answer (score 2):

It is trivially false for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: Or indeed any $({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})^3$ extension.

Comment: In general the discriminant of a $({\bf Z}/2{\bf Z})^k$ extension
is exactly equal to the product of the discriminants of the $2^k-1$
*minimal* subfields.  (Arguably the easiest proof is to compare the
functional equations of the zeta functions involved!)  For $k=2$
these are also the maximal subfields, but for $k \geq 3$
the product over the $2^k-1$ maximal subfields is strictly larger.